# Find the integral : $\int_{-t}^t e^{-|x|}\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

> **Problem :**
>   $$\int_{-t}^t e^{-|x|}\,dx$$

I tried this:
$$e^{-|x|} = \frac{1}{e^{|x|}}$$
Solution is given as same as integration of
$$e^x$$
reason that it is an even function

Comment: you can use $\int_{-t}^t = \int_{-t}^0+\int_0^t$ and get rid of that aboslute value.

Comment: Hpw to integrate 1/e^(x)

Comment: $\int e^{-x} dx = -e^{-x} + C$.  You can check by differentiating it.

Comment: an antiderivative of $e^{ax}$ is $\frac 1a e^{ax}$

Answer (score 7):

If $x<0$ then $|x|=-x$ and if $x>0$ then $|x|=x.$ So you have $ \displaystyle\int_{-t}^0 e^{-(-x)} \,dx + \int_0^t e^{-x}\, dx. $

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-t}^t e^{-|x|}\,dx=\int_{-t}^0 e^{-(-x)} \,dx + \int_0^t e^{-x}=2(1-e^{-t})$$

Answer (score 1):

$e^{-|x|}$ is an even function.

$\displaystyle \int_{-t}^{t} e^{-|x|}dx = 2 \displaystyle \int_{0}^{t}e^{-x}dx.$

Note: if $f(-x)= f(x):$

$\displaystyle \int_{-t}^{t} f(x)dx= $

$\displaystyle \int_{-t}^{0}f(x)dx + \displaystyle \int_{0}^{t}f(x)dx.$

Let $y=-x$ in the first integral:

$\displaystyle \int_{-t}^{0}f(x)dx = -\displaystyle  \int_{t}^{0}f(-y)dy=$

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{t}f(y)dy$, since $f(-y)= f(y)$.

Comment: Thanks for solution

Comment: Welcome.The even function , as you noticed, makes it a little easier.